# Why doesn't validating my SMTP server domain name and port work when running as a service under the local system account?

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, smtp, client

If I run this block of code through a console application running with Administrator privileges, it works just fine:

```
 public static bool ValidSMTP(string hostName, int port)
    {
        bool valid = false;
        TcpClient smtpTest = new TcpClient();
        smtpTest.Connect(hostName, port);
        if (smtpTest.Connected)
        {
            NetworkStream ns = smtpTest.GetStream();
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(ns);
            if (sr.ReadLine().Contains("220"))
            {
                valid = true;
            }
            smtpTest.Close();
        }
        return valid;
    }
```

But when I try to run it from my service located at C:\Code:\ServiceTesting\bin\ServiceHost.exe under the local system account, it fails to validate the server and times out with the following message on the call to smtpTest.Connect: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.

Comment: Try running the application as "NETWORK_SERVICE" instead.

Comment: I figured it might be a permissions thing but the problem is that network service causes other parts of this service's logic to fail.

Comment: @jgauffin - Is the local system account known to not work with TCP connections to an SMTP server or something?

Comment: Local system should work, but not Local service. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684188(v=vs.85).aspx. I would however avoid to run network services as Local System as the service gets a lot of permissions. Better to configure file access etc for a custom account that the service would run as.

Comment: The problem with Network Service is that it gets too little permissions. Unfortunately, the scope of my project is much bigger than just sending emails...now I'm not really sure what to do to be quite honest.

Comment: Create a new user account and configure it with the correct permissions.

Comment: @jgauffin - Just found out, that there's some sort of DNS issue, so the permissions weren't the problem. The server just only seems to work 50% of the time (roughly).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried running it from a console app vs. service at the same time? Also, could you test both approaches by making a series of requests to gather some statistics?

The point is that it could help isolate the issue from different factors other than different OS users like various network issues etc.

Feel free to give new details after doing that, if you'll be able to find out something new or intresting.